# Orchard CMS: How to create link with relative path by markdown editor?

Tags: orchardcms, orchard-modules, orchardcms-1.9

I want to create relative link in markup editor to link other page of current site. Site can be hosted as  http://localhost/OrchardLocal/ app on a developer environment and as http://somehost/ on production.

```
[my page](my-page)
```

returns

```
[my page](/my-page)
```

returns

So markdown inserts link as is without any application path in case of http://localhost/OrchardLocal/my-page.

Is there some workarond or solution?

Answer (score 0):

You should always setup your local dev environment like you do your prod environment, i.e. no `/OrchardLocal/`. Setup a local IIS and if you manage several site, either bind them to different host names, or to different ports.

Comment: Looks like I need to use regular expressions to fix those urls after Markdown.transform() Because I cannot find how can I extend Markdown.transform functionality.

Comment: You don't have to if your dev environment is correctly configured.